# MS Access: 100% CPU usage

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

We have an MS Access 2003 ADP application with SQL Server. Sometimes, without any apparent reason, this application starts consuming 100% of CPU time (50% on a dual-core CPU system). This is what Windows Task Manager and other process monitoring/analysis tools are showing, anyway. Usually, the only way to stop such CPU thrashing is to restart the application.

We still don't know how to trigger this problem at will. But I have a feeling that it usually happens when some of the forms get closed by a user.

**NB:** Recently we noticed that one of the forms consistently makes CPU usage raise to 100% whenever it gets minimized. Most of the time CPU usage goes back to normal when that form is "un-minimized". Perhaps, it's a different problem, but we'd like to uncover this mystery, too. :)

Googling for a solution of this problem didn't yield very good results. The most frequent theory is that MS Access gets into some sort of waiting-for-events loop which is practically harmless, performance-wise, because the thread running that loop has very low priority. This doesn't seem to help us because in our case (a) it certainly does hurt the system's performance and (b) it's still unclear what exactly makes Access to get into such "bad state" and how to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this CPU usage problem before in the past, but I don't remember if we ever discovered a solution or it just went away at some point.

In your post, you didn't mention reviewing the VBA.  I'd recommend looking for a loop that under certain conditions becomes an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is a hangover from this problem that access used to have in the "old" days

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160819

Whilst the article does say it is fixed in versions >=2000 it still might be something.

Comment: That's one of the articles I've already found before asking this question. The article suggests that Access throttles CPU because it's actively polling its message queue, doing this only during first 20-30 seconds of its "idle time" and not really affecting performance of other processes. In our case neither of those explanations/symptoms seems to apply. It might very well be a "new version" of the old problem, though... :)